# I created crud application using angular 11 and spring boot

Tags: angular, typescript

In angular I used template driven forms and my backend and frontend working correctly. but when i hit edit button in my studenttable component, I got this error in my console,

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at UpdateComponent_Template (update.component.html:11)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9600)
    at refreshView (core.js:9466)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10637)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9263)
    at refreshView (core.js:9516)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10591)
    at refreshView (core.js:9490)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10637)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9263)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6210
handleError @ core.js:6258
(anonymous) @ core.js:29567
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:372
run @ zone-evergreen.js:134
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:28503
tick @ core.js:29567
(anonymous) @ core.js:29436
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:372
onInvoke @ core.js:28574
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:371
run @ zone-evergreen.js:134
run @ core.js:28458
next @ core.js:29435
schedulerFn @ core.js:25912
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:25902
checkStable @ core.js:28511
onHasTask @ core.js:28591
hasTask @ zone-evergreen.js:426
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:447
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:274
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:195
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:582
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:491
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1600
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1626
```

when i debug i saw the error comming from  [(ngModel)]="studentObject.firstName" but i cannot slove this.

my studenttable.component.ts is ,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {StudentService} from "../../student.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-studenttable',
  templateUrl: './studenttable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./studenttable.component.css']
})
export class StudenttableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private studentService:StudentService) { }

  studentList:any
  listIndex:any
  msg=false;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.studentService.getAllStudentDetails().subscribe(result=>{
      this.studentList =result

    })
  }


  deleteStudent(id: number) {

    this.studentList.findIndex((value:any,i:number)=>{
        if(value.id==id){
          this.listIndex =i
        }
    })

    this.studentList.splice(this.listIndex,1)
    this.studentService.deleteStudentById(id).subscribe(result=>{
      this.msg=true;
    })
  }
}
```

my studenttable.component.html is ,

```
<div class="container mt-5" style="margin-bottom: 200px">

  <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success" *ngIf="msg">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Congratulations!! </strong> Student details deleted successfully.
  </div>

  <table class="table table-secondary">
    <thead>
    <tr >
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Action</th>

    </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let students of studentList">
      <td>{{students.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{students.lastName}}</td>

      <td>{{students.age}}</td>
      <td>{{students.phoneNumber}}</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mr-4" routerLink="/update/{{students.id}}">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteStudent(students.id)">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>


    </tbody>



  </table>








</div>
```

my update.component.ts is,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from "@angular/forms";
import {StudentService} from "../../student.service";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-update',
  templateUrl: './update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update.component.css']
})
export class UpdateComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private studentService:StudentService,private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) { }

  id:any
  studentObject:any
  msg=false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(result=>{
      this.id =result.get("id");
    })

    this.studentService.getStudentById(this.id).subscribe(result=>{
       this.studentObject =result;
    })


  }

  updateStudent(formdata: NgForm) {

    const updatedStudent ={
      firstName:this.studentObject.firstName,
      lastName:this.studentObject.lastName,
      age:this.studentObject.age,
      phoneNumber:this.studentObject.phoneNumber
    }

   this.studentService.updateStudentById(updatedStudent,this.id).subscribe(result=>{
     this.msg =true;
   })
  }
}
```

my update.component.html is,

```
<div class="container mt-5" style="margin-bottom: 200px">

  <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success" *ngIf="msg">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Congratulations!! </strong> Student details updated successfully.
  </div>

  <form #formUdata="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateStudent(formUdata)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputF">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputF"  placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="studentObject.firstName" #name1="ngModel" required   >

      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name1.valid">
        <span *ngIf="name1?.errors?.required">This field is required</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputL">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputL"  placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="studentObject.lastName" #name2="ngModel" required>

      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name2.valid">
        <span *ngIf="name2?.errors?.required">This field is required</span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputAge">Age</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAge"  placeholder="Enter Age" name="age" [(ngModel)]="studentObject.age" #name3="ngModel" required minlength="2" maxlength="2">

      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name3.valid">
        <span *ngIf="name3?.errors?.required">This field is required</span>
        <span *ngIf="name3?.errors?.minlength">You must enter atleast 2 numbers</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPNumber">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPNumber"  placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="phoneNumber"[(ngModel)]="studentObject.phoneNumber" #name4="ngModel" required minlength="10" maxlength="10">

      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name4.valid">
        <span *ngIf="name4?.errors?.required">This field is required</span>
        <span *ngIf="name4?.errors?.minlength">You must enter atleast 10 numbers</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!formUdata.valid">Update</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

service.ts is,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Student} from "./student";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }


  getAllStudentDetails():Observable<Student>{
   return this.httpClient.get<Student>("http://localhost:8080/student/getstudents")
  }

  addStudentDetails(data:object):Observable<Student>{
    return this.httpClient.post<Student>("http://localhost:8080/student/addstudent",data,);
  }

  getStudentById(id:number):Observable<Student>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Student>("http://localhost:8080/student/getstudent/"+id)
  }

  updateStudentById(data:object,id:number):Observable<Student>{
   return  this.httpClient.put<Student>("http://localhost:8080/student/update/"+id,data)
  }


   deleteStudentById(id:number):Observable<Student>{
    return this.httpClient.delete<Student>("http://localhost:8080/student/delete/"+id);
   }
```

}

**Plz help me to fix this error,**

Comment: That looks nothing like Spring Boot. More like NodeJS.

Comment: Are you sure that your backend response isn't undefined? ie `this.studentService.getStudentById(this.id)`

Comment: yes, I got details into my input fields.

Comment: Initialize `studentObject` so that it won't be undefined... or use an *ngIf on the form. Seems the easiest way here is just to initialize studentObject. Btw, lots of irrelevant code in your question. Took a while to find where your error is presented. You already knew where the error was happening, so showing the relevant code from that component would have been enough :)